# Wiring an Event Streams Kafka Topic to Grafana in IBM Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, ibm-eventstreams

How do I wire up a Kafka Topic from Event Streams to Grafana in IBM Cloud's console?  I can't seem to find a connector that will work, but the documentation seems to suggest that this is not only possible, but recommended.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation that you refer to?

Comment: What do you mean "wire up"? Grafana doesn't have a Kafka eventstore last time I checked...

Comment: In addition of the over 2 questions above, can you clarify if you're using Event Streams on Cloud or on Prem?